# Event Archive by Month

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, events

I'm creating an events site for a theatre in wordpress - at the moment I have set up a custom post type for Events and am using a custom field 'event_date' (which formats to YYYY-MM-DD) to order the events on their listing page and also move them to the archive if past todays date.

So far all working nicely.

Next up I need to create an month by month filter for the months in which shows appear however am a bit stumped. I guess I need to:
 - check the months which contain shows (not past) and output a list link these months to a template which filters to just show the relevant month..

Any pointers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok short of a better solution here is what I've come up with:

```
<?php
   $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 hours')); 
   query_posts(array(
      'post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => 99, 'meta_key' => 'event_date', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC', 
      'meta_query' => array(array(
         'key' => 'event_date',
         'meta-value' => $value, 
         'value' => $today, 
         'compare' => '>=', 
         'type' => 'CHAR'
       ))
   ));
   if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

The above gets all events in future of todays date

```
<?php
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586384/wordpress-events-grouped-by-month
    // for each month output the month once 
    $eventdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, "event_date", true);
    if(!isset($currentMonth) || $currentMonth != date("m", strtotime($eventdate))){
    $currentMonth = date("m", strtotime($eventdate));

    //make the month to pass into the url
    $month = date("Y", strtotime($eventdate)).'-'.date("m", strtotime($eventdate));
    $monthname = date("F", strtotime($eventdate));
?>
```

Kick out the month name once if posts exist in that date and manipulate for output.

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>whats-on-page/shows-by-month/?startdate=<?php echo($month); ?>-01&enddate=<?php echo($month); ?>-31&monthname=<?php echo ($monthname); ?>">
        <?php echo ($monthname); ?>
    </a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Output the html so we have a li and link - link goes to a page using a custom page template which pulls the parameters passed in the URL into a meta query like below:

```
   $start = $_GET["startdate"];
   $end = $_GET["enddate"];
   $monthname = $_GET["monthname"];
   // gets info from URL

   query_posts(array(
      'post_type' => 'events', //query “events”
      'posts_per_page' => 10,
      'paged' => $paged,
      'meta_key' => 'event_date',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value',
      'order' => 'ASC', //sort in ascending order
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'value' => array($start, $end),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            )
        ) // meta query between dates
   ));
   if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

So now I have a dynamic listing in the sidebar to link to a custom page template which filters by month, effectively recreating the post archive effect using a custom date field.

Sure I could probably create some URL rewrites to make this work with pretty URLs too but thats for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Create an archive index for your custom post type (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index) first.

I grabbed the next part from another website (http://wpgarage.com/code-snippets/how-to-create-an-archive-based-on-custom-fields-not-publish-date-in-wordpress/)

I found this wonderful date field plugin (http://matth.eu/wordpress-date-field-plugin) which lets  you sort posts by the date entered in the custom fields.  Here’s what I did:

1. Upload the plugin and activate it
2. Opened the archive page template you created and added a query. The query checks for posts that have a date filled in and the orders it from oldest to newest.

`<?php query_posts('meta_key=date_value&orderby=meta_value&order=DESC'); ?>`

1. I replaced a typical date function within the loop `<?php the_time(‘j M Y’); ?>` with

`<?php echo date(“l jS \of F Y”, get_post_meta($post->ID, ‘date_value’, true));?>`

You'll now have a list of posts by date, in your archive.. From there it shouldn't be to hard to take the next step and filter by dates etc.

Comment: Thanks Simon, this is where I'm up to already I have two archives but generating the upcoming events by month in the sidebar is the tricky bit.